# Unique Complete Reducibility of Finite Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Maschke's Theorem states that every complex representation $(\rho,V)$ of a finite group $G$ can be written as a direct sum of irreducible representations that form subsets of V, such that $V = V_1\oplus V_2 \oplus...\oplus V_N$, where $V_i$ are irreducible representations of $G$. This seems like a silly question, but I would like to check - do the irreducible representations of$G$ direct-summed over have to be sub-representations of $G$ in V under the map $\rho$ as well, or could some of them be sub-representations under a different map? Is this "decomposition" of V into a direct sum of irreducible representations unique? If so, how should I prove this fact? Does this "decomposition" of V include all irreducible representations in V under the map $\rho$?

Comment: I don't understand your terminology, and I am not sure what you are asking. I have never head of a *sub-representation*. A representation (such as $\rho$) is a homomorphism. $V$ is usually called a module, and the $V_i$ are submodules. But what exactly do you mean by "a subrepresentation of $G$ in $V$ under the map $\rho$"?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you are working over $\mathbb{C}$.

First, given any representation, it is not true that every irreducible representation is a direct summand.  Consider a group with $2$ irreducible representations, and then take one of them.

Second, the decomposition of any representation into irreducible components is unique, up to order, and isomorphism (see Derek's comment below).  This can be proved using Schur's lemma.

Your last question is sort of similar to your first, in that not all irreducible representations are sub-representations of any representation.  There is a special representation though, called the regular representation (G acting on itself by left multiplication) which does have every irreducible representation in its decomposition.  What's more, the number of times each irreducible representation appears is equal to its dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I did not phrase my first question well. I meant whether the theorem only allowed you to "decompose" V into sub-representations formed using the map $\rho$, or whether it also allowed you to include some irreducible sub-representations formed using a different map, $\pi$, as summands as well.

Comment: The submodules $V_i$ in a decomposition are unique up to isomorphism, but they are not necessarily unique in an absolute sense. For example, if $G$ is the trivial group and $V$ has dimension two, then $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ with the $V_i$ of dimension one, but there are infinitely many different choices of $V_1$ and $V_2$.